# Fibrant (Kan complex) geometric meaning

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff

A simplicial set $X$ is said to be fibrant (or Kan complex) if it satisfies the following homotopy extension condition for each $i$:

Let $x_0,\dots,x_{i-1},x_{i+1},\dots,x_n\in X_{n-1}$ be any elements that are matching faces with respect to $i$. Then there exists an element $w\in X_n$ such that $d_jw=x_j$ for $j\neq i$.

What would be the geometric meaning of the definition above? For example for an ordinary simplex?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You should think of it as something that is obviously true when looking at a topological space regarded as a simplicial set.

Comment: Page 38-39 of Friedman's Elementary Introduction might be helpful to visualize it. http://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.4221.pdf

Comment: Thanks for introducing Friedman's paper